# How to Run jetty on different maven profile

Tags: java, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using **maven-jetty-plugin** .I have created two profile for test and development.
Here is my pom

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <build>

    <finalName>Authorization</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>8080</port>
              <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
      </profile>
        <profile>
      <id>development</id>
      <build>

    <finalName>AuthorizationTest</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
```

So,when i run jetty:run i want to profile it for test and development.

Like
 **jetty:run -Ptest** for test profile and **jetty:run -Pdevelopment** .

When i run jetty:run -Ptest it does not work.**Do i need to do extra configuration to make it run?** **If it is not possible from plugin then is there any alternative to run jetty on different maven profile?** Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have neither bound the jetty plug in to a phase nor did you give it a goal to execute. Contrary to many other plugins, the jetty-maven-plugin's goals are not tied to default phases. BTW: You are using a hopelessly outdated version of the jetty-plugin. Since that time, it moved away from mortbay to eclipse foundation and got a major revamp - at least one time. I have adjusted the example below accordingly:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.mwmahlberg.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>start-jetty-in-profiles</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!-- Adjust to your packaging here -->
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- this will fire up jetty as soon as you reach the integration-test phase in the test profile -->
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>8080</port>
              <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>development</id>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined in my IntelliJ a new maven command, as following:

```
clean package jetty:run -Pdev
```

It should work! The profile dev was used to replace params in config files during development phase.

I still use jetty plugin from mortbay:

```
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
```